# Finding the torsion of a space curve which is piecewise planar.

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

I am trying to describe a space curve that is constructed using piecewise planar circular arcs and a straight line segment. Basically I have three circular arcs, all of same curvature but in three different planes connected together with continuity of tangents and then a straight line segment connecting two open ends of the circular arcs again in a $C^1$ continuous fashion. It is apparent that the torsion, if it can be defined at all, is zero almost everywhere apart from on a finite set of four points where there is a transition from circular arc in one plane to that in another and finally from circular arcs to straight line segments. [image: Piecewise circular space curve].

Is it possible to define a frame for this curve and also describe the torsion at the four points? The curvature is constant on the circular arcs and zero on the line segment. How would one go about trying to describe this curve otherwise? Are there curves of this type that have ben studied elsewhere?

Comment: No, the Frenet frame is undefined (except for the unit tangent) at the junction points, and curvature is defined only accidentally. Torsion certainly is not defined in a traditional sense. You can perhaps define it distributionally by looking at the change in the unit normal vectors to the planes, but I am dubious.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for replying. So, even if I were to try a parallel adapted frame, it would still be useless. Is it however possible to define the total torsion or twist(trying to avoid using the torsion term) in this case?

Comment: For the Bishop frame, you still need a $C^2$ curve. To define the total twist, you ordinarily need a $C^1$ normal vector field, which obviously won't exist here.

Comment: @TedShifrin Right, because the curvature itself is not well defined, thanks.